# Xamarin Forms Commands with Async Methods without lambda

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous, command

I am trying to pass an asynchronous method to a command in xamarin forms. In microsoft docs, the sample codes are provided with lambda expressions. As I am pretty new at c#, I want to see the explicit form of it to understand the concept clearly:

The code with lambda:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>(
            async (Type pageType) =>
            {
                Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            });
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { private set; get; }
}
```

So, my question is how to retype NavigationCommand without lambda. I think It would be more beneficial to the beginners.
Thanks a lot for any respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the following code

```
NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>((pageType) => TestCommand(pageType));
```

```
async void TestCommand(Type pageType)
{
  Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
  await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

If your method has no argument, you could init it like

```
NavigateCommand = new Command(TestCommand);
```

```
async void TestCommand()
{
   //...      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the lambda is still there. Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: Because your method contains parameter Pagetype .